# Level of significance and acceptance and rejection of null hypothesis

Tags: chi-squared-test

Why do we reject null hypothesis of a Goodness of test when the Chi square statistic is more than the  tabulated value of chi-square at say 5% level of significance and accept when it is less?

What does it mean to have a Chi-square value **more** or **less** than the value assigned to a certain level of significance?

Comment: The null hypothesis is usually set up as the uninteresting hypothesis.  So we attempt to reject it.  If we can't reject at a particular significance level that does not mean that we should accept it.

Comment: I didn't say that. My question is why accept when more and reject when less? May be you should consider rereading the query, my main question is the second one.

Comment: What level of Type I error you will tolerate is a subjective economic decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a chi-squared value **more** than the value at a certain significance level means that under the null hypothesis the observed chi-squared value is **more unlikely** than your desired level of significance. A smaller chi squared value means the observed values are more likely under the null hypothesis. As the chi squared value gets **higher**, the likelihood of seeing your observations under the null hypothesis **decreases**, so rejecting the null becomes more and more attractive

Comment: Is this consistent with any type of test statistic, like goodness of fit and test for homogeinity of chi-square?

Comment: Not sure if you are specifically discussing chi-squared type tests or other tests, but this is generally how things go. Your test statistic increases as the observations become less likely under the null hypothesis.